# Laravel queue, redirect after dispatch

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-jobs

I have job class in my package. Function is simple but time consuming. I'd like send it to run in background.

```
php artisan queue:work
```

works.

```
<?php
namespace Mypackage\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class  StartLottery implements ShouldQueue{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $count;
    public $competition;

    public function __construct($count, $competition)
    {
      $this->count = $count;
      $this->competition = $competition;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
//code body
    }
}
```

and in controller

```
dispatch((new StartLottery($count, $id))->onQueue('high'));
```

My default connection for queue is database.

My goal is run this job immediately in background and unlock browser to do another instructions like redirect.

Unfortunately next things are doing after finish job. Finally user wait long time on response from server after his request.

Thanks in advance for any hints how can I move this job to background.

environment:

- Laravel 5.4
- php 5.6
- debian 8

Comment: Do you have a worker running?

Comment: `php artisan queue:work`  and all time is working

Comment: Try `php artisan queue:work --queue=high,low`

Comment: Still lock browser

Comment: Do you see any messages in the terminal when the job is processed?

Comment: no, terminal is empty

Comment: Also my jobs database is empty. It's probably not normal.

Comment: Try `php artisan queue:listen` to see if the jobs are actually placed on the queue

Comment: Have you added the queue tables to the database?

Comment: I added. What I shame... I've been changes default connection but in config file not in .env and laravel had bad connection. Thanks for your help. Now it works correct.